# How to decorate a class so that i could be able to change the attribute of a class in run time

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-decorators, python-class

```
def decorator(cls):
    #code

    return cls

@decorator
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    ssid = db.Column(db.String(20))    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}',{self.password})"
```

I want to decorate a class such that i could be able to access the value of ssid  in decorator function and add a new attribute to the class.As the new attribute requires the value of ssid.

```
user = User(username='prince',ssid='9734ait')
db.session.add(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an appropriate use case for a decorator... seems to me you can just use inheritance and add a new attribute in the `__init__`. For instance:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    ssid = db.Column(db.String(20))    

    def __init__(self, *args, password=None, your_new_attribute=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.password = hash(ssid)
        self.your_new_attribute = your_new_attribute

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}',{self.password})"
```

Comment: Hi @cosmic_inquiry I am exploring the possibilities of decorating the class.I know i should provide APIs to calculate the hash of the password and verification of passwords. But i want to know is it possible in this case to decorate the class As i want to decorate the class with encryptor function which calculate the hash value of the ssid and store it in a new attribute of class called password.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a decorator:

```
class Decorator:
    def __call__(self, cls):
        class Inner(cls):
            cls.password = cls.ssid[::-1]
        return Inner

@Decorator()
class User:
    ssid = "fooo" 

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User({self.ssid}, {self.password})"

u = User()
print(u)
```

Output:

```
User(fooo, ooof)
```

Comment: I want to decorate the class which is inherited from db.Model class of flask-sqlalchemy.I can't be able access the variables of the class in wrapper by any mean.

Comment: Hi @cosmic_inquiry I am sharing you the location of the file please look into it. [github repo link](https://github.com/princekrroshan01/flask-hedcrypt/blob/master/flask_crypto/testing_decorater.py). An issue is also raised in the repo. if you solve it than that will be the great help for me.

Comment: That's not true- sqlalchemy models are python classes like any other. you can define or override methods, including __init__ or __repr__. You can also add attributes. The "map an attribute to a db column part" comes from the Descriptormagic in `db.Column` - a field that is NOT a db.Column acts just like a normal field.

Answer (score 0):

Would defining a property within the decorator be sufficient for your use case ?

For example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///site.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Encryptor:
    def __call__(self, cls):
        class Inner(cls):

            # define a getter function to return the password
            def password_getter(self):
                # return the calculated password here now you have access to username and ssid
                return f'{self.username} - {self.ssid}'.upper()

            setattr(cls, "password", property(fget=password_getter))

        return Inner


@Encryptor()
class User5(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    ssid = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}',{self.ssid}; PASSWORD: {self.password})"


db.create_all()

user = User5(username="prince", ssid="3456ait")
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()

users = User5.query.all()
print(users)
```

Comment: Yes it works, Can you please help me with one more thing. Is the the extensions objects like db for flask-sqlalchemy db=SQLAlchemy(app). gets stored inside the app context so that one could access the object from anywhere in the package.If yes then how i should i access those.

Comment: Please look into the gist  for what i want to do.(https://gist.github.com/princekrroshan01/441d1a40ce5df83ee9f2df47d25a010e)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said that the actual goal is to encrypt passwords on the way in and out of the class. Sqlalchemy offers this using hybrid properties. This is an example from one of my projects-

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(255))
    hashed_password = Column("password", String(255))


    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self.hashed_password

    @password.setter  # type: ignore
    def password(self, value):
        rounds = 4
        if not isinstance(value, bytes):
            value = value.encode("utf-8")
        self.hashed_password = hashpw(value, gensalt(rounds)).decode("utf-8")
```

(so only the hashed password is stored in the database in this case- to check the password, you hash the input and compare it to user.password)